# XSD with import in Gradle resource folder can't be read by SAX

Tags: java, validation, jaxb, xsd, gradle

I have generated my XSD validation files with Schemagen.

There is both an one-file validation XSD and a two-file validation XSD with imports.

There is no problem to include the one-file validation XSD file in my Java application for validation from the gradle resource folder. But if I try to load the two-file validation XSD with import from the gradle resource folder like shown below, it will crash with the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 98; src-resolve: 
Name "ns1:stringArray" kann nicht als "type definition"-Komponente aufgelöst werden.
Means in english: name can't be resolved as type definition component
```

If the two-file validation XSD is located in the gradle source folder, it works properly, so there can't be any error in the file except the resolving of the import location.

My XSD file looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="" xmlns:ns1="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array"
  xmlns:tns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:import namespace="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array" schemaLocation="schema2.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="Degrees" type="tns:degreeCourse"/>

  <xs:complexType name="degreeCourse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="e" type="ns1:stringArray" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

It's loaded by:

```
Schema schema = schemaFactory
            .newSchema(getStreamSourceOfSchema("schema1.xsd"));

private StreamSource getStreamSourceOfSchema(String schemaName) {
    return new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
            "/" + schemaName));
}
```

Although using src/main/resources before the schema location in the import statement didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: My actual solution was to put everything together in one file, but I still couldn't find a solution for imported files.